# play and record audio simultaneously in J2ME?

Tags: audio, java-me, record

Is it possible to play and record audio simultaneously in Nokia s40 phones with J2ME or anything else?

---

Is it also possible to record and stream,like I record and use commit() to get the byte array,
but the commit() takes at least 250ms ,even the record length is 10 ms,and it irrationally takes 280ms if the record length is 10s etc, the device I tested is Nokia 6300 s40 device.
How can I prevent the gap?

Answer (score 2):

Look at this [discussion on Nokia forum.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?219548-NOT-MMAPI) It will helps you. Also look on [some interesting discussion](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&biw=1280&bih=658&q=+site%3adeveloper.nokia.com+play+and+record+sound+simultaneously+%2B+j2me#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=site%3adeveloper.nokia.com+play+and+record+simultaneously+%2B+j2me&pbx=1&oq=site%3adeveloper.nokia.com+play+and+record+simultaneously+%2B+j2me&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=932127l932127l0l933321l1l1l0l0l0l0l140l140l0.1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=722449f05f5718c3&biw=1280&bih=658) like this.